# How to get the bin value by qcut

Tags: python, pandas

I applied pd.qcut to cut my data in to 24 bins.
How can I get the bin value into a list? [-0.001,1.05,2.46,3.797...]

```
res = pd.qcut(df['field'], 24)
res.cat.categories
IntervalIndex([(-0.001, 1.05], (1.05, 2.46], (2.46, 3.797], (3.797, 5.308], (5.308, 7.16] ... (71.1, 85.6], (85.6, 105.295], (105.295, 132.896], (132.896, 184.0], (184.0, 912.9]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `retbins=True` argument to `qcut`.

```
res, bins = pd.qcut(df['field'], 24, retbins=True)
```

Alternatively, try:

```
res.cat.categories.values.tolist()
```

This will get you a list of `pandas._libs.interval.Interval` objects, which contain both the edges as well as if those edges are inclusive.

Link to the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html).